# Objective-C - making a Unity plugin from Aruts

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

What would be the best approach to making a plugin from a full Xcode Project? I've tried creating simple "get numbers from Objective-C" type of plugins, but this seems far more complex.

I'm trying to see if I can get the functionality of [Aruts by Simon Epskamp](https://github.com/Epskampie/ios-coreaudio-example) onto a Unity game. What Aruts does is take the audio heard by the mic and output it to the headphones / speakers.

So far, what I've tried is to import `IosAudioController.m`, `IosAudioController.h` (renamed TestScript), and my own "extern" file that accesses Start and Stop functionality from said files.

While it does run without errors, all I'm hearing are rapid-firing clicking sounds, and per the comments, the function `recordingCallback` is not being called.

I also tried to take bits of the Aruts `main.m` and tried to stick it into the Unity project's `main.mm`, to no success. I'll update this with code when I can get my hands on it.

EDIT:

Here's my `TestExtern.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TestScript.h"

void TestStartAudioRec() {
    [iosAudio start];
}

void TestStopAudioRec() {
    [iosAudio stop];
}
```

Here's the Unity project's `main.mm`:

```
#include "RegisterMonoModules.h"
#include "RegisterFeatures.h"
#include <csignal>
#import "TestScript.h"

static const int constsection = 0;

void UnityInitTrampoline();

const char* AppControllerClassName = "UnityAppController";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    iosAudio = [[TestScript alloc] init];

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        UnityInitTrampoline();
        UnityParseCommandLine(argc, argv);

        RegisterMonoModules();
        NSLog(@"-> registered mono modules %p\n", &constsection);
        RegisterFeatures();
        std::signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);

        int retval = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, [NSString stringWithUTF8String:AppControllerClassName]);

        NSLog(@"After retval");

        [pool release];

        return retval;
    }

    return 0;
}

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR && TARGET_TVOS_SIMULATOR

#include <pthread.h>

extern "C" int pthread_cond_init$UNIX2003(pthread_cond_t *cond, const pthread_condattr_t *attr)
{ return pthread_cond_init(cond, attr); }
extern "C" int pthread_cond_destroy$UNIX2003(pthread_cond_t *cond)
{ return pthread_cond_destroy(cond); }
extern "C" int pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003(pthread_cond_t *cond, pthread_mutex_t *mutex)
{ return pthread_cond_wait(cond, mutex); }
extern "C" int pthread_cond_timedwait$UNIX2003(pthread_cond_t *cond, pthread_mutex_t *mutex,
                                               const struct timespec *abstime)
{ return pthread_cond_timedwait(cond, mutex, abstime); }

#endif // TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR && TARGET_TVOS_SIMULATOR
```

Perhaps there's something wrong with it. Compare it with the `main.m` for Aruts:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "IosAudioController.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSLog(@"main");
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    iosAudio = [[IosAudioController alloc] init];

    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];

    return retVal;
}
```

Any suggestions?